# jest test case is failing for react functional component

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, ts-jest, jest-fetch-mock

My code is failing when i run this test.
I have tried

```
await expect(API().isFileAvailable).rejects.toEqual(Promise.reject(new Error('Bad input')));
```

But this doesn't work

```
File: async (a: string, b: string | undefined, c: string | undefined) => {
        if (!a&& !b) {
            return Promise.reject(new Error('Bad input'));
        }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you read Jest's documentation? https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#rejects

Comment: Also, when using a Promise with `async`, we generally don't use `Promise.reject()` but prefer to `throw`.

Answer (score 0):

According to Jest's documentation, the [`rejects` keyword](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tothrowerror) should be used with [`toThrow()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tothrowerror) (which is an alias to `toThrowError()`).

You can directly use a string to match the error message, or a regex, or a `Error` object.

Your assertion should work with the following:

```js
await expect(API().isFileAvailable).rejects.toThrow('Bad input');
```

Also, you should probably use `throw` in your code. Using `Promise.reject()` is less readable and the benefits of async/await is precisely to automatically reject when you throw an error.

```js
File: async (a: string, b: string | undefined, c: string | undefined) => {
        if (!a&& !b) {
            // return Promise.reject(new Error('Bad input'));
            throw new Error('Bad input');
        }
}
```